# html form with inner table not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I  need to edit a web app written in PHP and HTML. There is an opening `<form>` and closing `</form>` tag. In between is an HTML table to layout the form fields. There is a table within this table and form fields also inside this inner table, but these aren't showing in PHP when the page is submitted. Fields (and their values) in the outer table are. How can I begin to trouble shoot this?

```
<form>

  <table>

    <tr>rows of fields</tr>
    <tr>
      <table>
        <tr>an inner table of stuff</tr>
      </table>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>
```

P.S. I know, tables instead of CSS, that's a story for another day!

Comment: I don't think this is a PHP issue, I think the problem is the "table within a table". Try taking out all formatting (leaving just the form elements) and see if it works then. That is how you could beging to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ensure that all form elements have valid name attributes. Best if you can post the HTML in full so we can see. Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what IS coming through.

Comment: The inner table will be placed after the outer table, so this should actually work. But better validate your HTML instead. Will help you to get better results faster. And BTW: Using tables to format forms can be OK, it's not perfect, but there are reasons to do that actually, especially if you're not picky on specific browser versions.

Comment: @PeeHaa I would post the HTML but its massive but the above is an accurate cut out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

table within a table is not valid. Instead do it like this

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>rows of fields</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>an inner table of stuff</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: The <td> (column) was the missing key :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to make sure the HTML is valid: http://validator.w3.org/

Once it validates, it will just work.

Comment: Its not a public facing site so I can't use that...Although it gave me idea to copy the HTML generated by the PHP page somewhere that is public facing so I can use the validator, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is invalid HTML. `<table>` tags and `<tr>` tags can't contain other `<table>` tags, you need to at least use a `<td>`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear I will update my original post, the inner table is inside a a pair of <tr>'s. Does that make it valid?

Comment: @javano, no, it should be inside `<td>`, not `<tr>`. Do take a look at the documentation for [`<table>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html), especially the `TBODY` section. A `<tr>` tag can only contain `<th>` or `<td>` tags.

Comment: @javano No, that doesn't make it valid; the second `<table>` should be inside a `<td>`. Your form troubles are probably due to the browser trying to fix your HTML, which results in the form being closed prematurely. A tool like Firebug or Web Inspector should show that. It'll probably look something like this: `<form></form> <table></table>` instead of `<form> <table></table> </form>`. When faced with invalid HTML (especially when dealing with tables) the browser is free to re-order and close things until it makes sense.

Comment: Surprisingly using Chrome I could see that wasn't the case and it was all displayed correctly, as you mentioned, the <td>'s were the missing part :)

Comment: @javano, sure, even if the HTML is invalid, the browsers will still display it, each in their own way. This is called [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and you should definitely not rely on it. It's much easier and a lot more reliable to write valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td>rows of fields</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>an inner table of stuff</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```